# Can't Delete folder as it's in use.

Tags: c#, io, directory

I have an issue with an auto update software that I am trying to make.  The application runs as a server application and checks via FTP for updates and downloads them if there is a newer version available.  This then unzips a folder called update in the programs root directory.  it then launches a file called update.bat that does any file copying etc that I may need to do for that update.  Once this is finished the update.bat launches the new server application.  Once the program goes to check for updates again it is suppose to delete the update directory that is in the root directory of the server application as well as the update.rar file that was downloaded from the update server.   All of this works perfectly except the folder is being used and will not delete.  I have read all kinds of things about releasing the handle and changing the current directory etc.. but just can't seem to get it to work. I would appreciate someone helping me out here.  Here is the code for this update.

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories("C:/my update dir"))
        {

            if (s.Contains("Instance"))
            {

                var _instance = Regex.Match(s, @"\d+");

                Process p = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo pinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                pinfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                pinfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/mySQL/bin";
                pinfo.Arguments = "/C mysql.exe -u** -p** dbnameHere" + _instance.ToString() +
                    " < \"C:/my update dir/update/update.sql\"";
                p.StartInfo = pinfo;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
                p.Close();
                p.Dispose();
                Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:/");
            }
        }

        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:/");
        this.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess that your problem is here:

> Once this is finished the update.bat launches the new server
>   application.

Windows is going to "lock" the directories all the way down to the .BAT file. So if the .BAT runs a server process from that directory, that process is going to inherit the CWD and file descriptors of the calling process.

It's not clear from your code that this is what's happening, but you may also want to try changing the CWD prior to spawning the process.

Comment: yes that worked great.  Just needed to change the directory in the .bat file and it released the handle.